# Can't free/deallocate space in my pop function?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, free

Here is my code for pop:

```
int pop (struct_of_ints *head_node){
int val;
if (head_node == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "Empty stack.\n");
    return -1;
}
else {
    struct_of_ints *curr;
    struct_of_ints *prev;
    curr = head_node;
    prev = NULL;

        while (curr->next != NULL) {
            prev = curr;
            curr = curr->next;
        }

        val = curr->value;

        if (prev == NULL) 
            head_node = NULL;
    else 
            prev->next = curr->next;
        free(curr)
        return val;


}

}
```

When I try to free(curr), however, I get a segmentation fault and when I run valgrind I get messages like "Invalid free() / delete / delete[]", "Address 0x51c1f60 is 16 bytes inside a block of size 32 free'd", and "Invalid read of size 8"...I have no idea what's wrong. If anyone could help I'd appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: I recommend you use a double-linked list instead, with a tail pointer. Will make life simpler if you want to remove from the tail. Or, if you're implement a stack, just push/pop at the head instead.

Comment: compile the code with `-g` flag, run `gdb` to check your errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing the pointer *head_node, in the function, which is getting passed by value. To update *head_node, try passing **head_node, and change the code as::

```
int pop (struct_of_ints **head_node)
{
    int val;
    if (*head_node == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Empty stack.\n");
        return -1;
    }
    else 
    {
        struct_of_ints *curr;
        struct_of_ints *prev;
        curr = *head_node;
        prev = NULL;
        while (curr->next != NULL) 
        {
            prev = curr;
            curr = curr->next;
        }

        val = curr->value;

        if (prev == NULL) 
            *head_node = NULL;
        else 
            prev->next = curr->next;
        free(curr)
        return val;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that this happens only after you popped all nodes, and then try to pop one more. This is because your assignment to `head_node` inside the function will not be propagated to the code that called the function. `head_node` is a local variable inside the function, and you need to pass it as a reference (i.e. as a pointer to a pointer).

What happens when the last node is popped, is that the function free's it, but the code calling it will still have the pointer. So the next call will be with a pointer to free'd memory which will cause *undefined behavior* when that pointer is accessed. Undefined behavior often results in crashes.